# Iterate through list of plots in Patchworklib

Tags: python, plot

I would like to iterate through a list of data series in a Python numpy matrix using something like https://github.com/ponnhide/patchworklib, however, the example code given on the page only allows for manually entering each plot. Is there a way to save each plot in `patchworklib` in a list of plots and then iteratively print them out so they all display on a single page, like `do.call("grid.arrange", c(plot_list))` does in R?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of solutions. The first two utilse `plotnine` and `patchworklib`. The latter 3 solutions are alternatives you might find of interest.

[image: results]

```
import pandas as pd

#Synthetic data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': np.arange(0, 50) / 10,
    'var1': 2 * np.random.randn(50),
    'var2': np.random.randn(50),
    'var3': np.random.rand(50)
})

#
# [1] Print list of plotnine ggplot objects
#
import plotnine as pp

#Append ggplot objects to a list
ggplots = []
for col in df.columns:
    ggplots.append( pp.ggplot(df, pp.aes(x=col)) + pp.geom_histogram() )
    
#Display list objects
for gg in ggplots:
    display(gg)
    
#
# [2] Display/arrange figures using patchworklib
#
from patchworklib import load_ggplot
from copy import deepcopy

def pw(ggplot):
    return load_ggplot(deepcopy(ggplot))

( pw(ggplots[0]) | pw(ggplots[1]) / pw(ggplots[2]) ).savefig()

#Three alternative methods
#
#
# [3] Using pandas standard functionality
#
df.plot(x='time') #all cols plotted against x
df.plot(kind='line', x='time', y=['var2', 'var3']) #selected cols plotted against x

#
# [4] Scatter matrix of all columns
#
import pandas.plotting
pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix(df)

#
# [5] Using seaborn.objects (similar to layering in ggplot)
#
import seaborn.objects as so
(
    so.Plot(df, x='time')
    .pair(y=['var1', 'var2', 'var3'], wrap=3)
    .add(so.Dots())
)
```